# How to check if value begins with ...?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to check if value begins with "TLR". I have tried:

```
<xs:element name="VoucherCode" maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="1">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="^TLR" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [XML Schema Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html):

> Particularly noteworthy is the complete absence of anchors like the
>   caret and dollar, word boundaries, and lookaround. XML schema always
>   implicitly anchors the entire regular expression. The regex must match
>   the whole element for the element to be considered valid.

Therefore, the above example should have been:

```
<xs:element name="VoucherCode" maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="1">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="TLR.*" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```